# What is the difference between const virtual and virtual const?

Tags: c++, constants, virtual

I saw that some function in C++ was declared as

```
virtual const int getNumber();
```

But what is the difference if the function is declared as the following?

```
const virtual int getNumber();
```

What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Note that `const` doesn't do anything useful here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As was already said, there is no difference. However, note that these two **do** differ:

```
virtual const int getNumber();
virtual       int getNumber() const;
```

In the first method, `const` refers to the returned value of type `int`.

In the second method, `const` refers to the object the method is called on; that is, `this` will have type `T const *` inside this method, - you will be able to call only `const` methods, modify only `mutable` fields and so on.

Comment: @TankorSmash added explanation to the answer

Answer (score 21):

There's no difference. A declaration's specifiers can usually be written in any order.

Comment: Usually? Can you think of an exception?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Not off the top of my head, but I don't want to state that there aren't any because I don't know for sure. You can read all fifteen pages of [dcl.spec] if you want to check for yourself.

Comment: Ah, I did that, some time ago. That's why I wondered when you said 'usually'.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference. If we look at the grammar summary for a *decl-specifier-seq* we can see that it's defined in a recursive manner:

```
decl-specifier:
     type-specifier

decl-specifier-seq:
     decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq
```

The only restriction is that `const` and `volatile` can be combined with any type specifier except themselves (no `const const`, `volatile volatile`, etc), there is no rule on the order in which you use them.

Comment: @anatolyg The question specifies neither syntax or semantics. It just asks for the difference. This answer starts by saying there is no difference, which is correct, and supports it by an extract from the syntax which is also correct. For this answer to be wrong, it would be necessary to posit that the AST preserved the order of the specifiers and then reacted differently to different orders, and any such claim would need to be backed by some actual evidence.

Answer (score 2):

No difference. You can apply modifiers in your favourite order.